# Unable to run curlpp library on c++

Tags: c++, homebrew

I am compiling a C++11 program with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/curlpp/0.8.1_1/include/ -Iinclude  -lcurl
```

Yet I am getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup()", referenced from:
      _main in main-18dda9.o
  "curlpp::Cleanup::~Cleanup()", referenced from:
      _main in main-18dda9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Comment: What is the platform you are building the program for? What is the platform for which curlpp was built? Looks like you are cross-compiling, however you have not built the curlpp library for target platform.. Can you provide additional information about your build environment.

Comment: @DarkSorrow M1 Mac book Pro

Comment: Is it native build or are you cross-compiling? Are you using any package manager for library or are you manually building the library?

Comment: I just ran brew install curlpp. Doesn't this install the native build?

Comment: It should. Try running lipo -info library_name and post the output

Comment: @DarkSorrow fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: curlpp (No such file or directory)

Comment: Check if libcurlpp.a is available in the location in case of static build or libcurlpp.so in case of shared library.

Comment: @DarkSorrow libcurlpp.a

Comment: Is the file available at the mentioned location?

Comment: @DarkSorrow What file? The thing that confuses me is that I am doing the exact same process to import other libraries (Boost library) and it works.

Comment: Is  libcurlpp.a located in the folder where you are searching for the library.

Comment: @DarkSorrow No. The folder where I am searching is /opt/homebrew/Cellar/curlpp/0.8.1_1/include while the folder containing libcurlpp.a is /opt/homebrew/Cellar/curlpp/0.8.1_1/lib

Comment: Go to the folder containing libcurlpp.a and type lipo -info libcurlpp.a

Comment: @DarkSorrow Non-fat file: libcurlpp.a is architecture: arm64

Comment: Run uname -a and paste the output.

Comment: Try also to give complete path of the library while building the program.